# Can I find the height of the Title bar in a Powerbuilder window?

Tags: windows, location, powerbuilder, titlebar

In Powerbuilder I have created a window with datawindows on it. I now am to create a subwindow (one that appears on top of the last window) only I would like it to appear in a specific place. However, though I can use the .X and .Y and .Height and so on commands, both window and subwindow have titles on them which throws the Y location completely.

Is there a way to find the height of the title bar, or even another way to find the location?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Function integer GetSystemMetrics(integer nIndex) Library "user32.dll"

CONSTANT Integer SM_CYCAPTION = 4
Integer li_pixels, li_pbunits

li_pixels = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION)
li_pbunits = PixelsToUnits(li_pixels, YPixelsToUnits!)

Comment: @HugMyster: Actually, you only call a function from a system library already used by quite every Windows program. And since the title bar is not painted by PB but the system (differently depending on the Windows version) it is logical to ask to the system. PB only cares about what is in the "client rect"inside of the borders, as any other program (but special cases).

Comment: In that case, thank you Seki. You'll have to forgive my ignorance on this sort of thing...